# jQuery keyboard press and focus to textbox (Different case)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS like this :

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

if (key.match(/[0]/) && !$('#acc').is(':focus'))
{
    $('#acc').focus();
    $('#acc').val($('#acc').val() + key);
}
else if (key.match(/[PA]/) && !$('#code_read_box').is(':focus'))
{
    $('#code_read_box').focus();
    $('#code_read_box').val($('#code_read_box').val() + key);
}
});
```

and the HTML like this :

```
<input type="text" id="acc" value=""/>
<br>
<input type="text" id="code_read_box" value=""/>
```

Now when I test to type keyboard with "0" (without any focus to textbox, it's auto focus), then it will focus to the textbox acc. But problem when I type "PA0L02", the first "PA" will focus to textbox code read box, but after "0L02", it will focus to textbox acc.

What I want is how to keep the text input if it contains "0" in textbox code read box?

You can see [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eWm5c/)

Comment: Can you explain again what is your desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what yo uare trying to achieve, but if you remove the .focus lines, that will stop the cursor jumping around...

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    if (key.match(/[PA]/) && !$('#acc').is(':focus')) {
        //$('#acc').focus();
        $('#acc').val($('#acc').val() + key);
    }
    else if (key.match(/[0]/) && !$('#code_read_box').is(':focus')) {
        //$('#code_read_box').focus();
        $('#code_read_box').val($('#code_read_box').val() + key);
    }
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWm5c/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after the `.keyup` line:

```
if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input')
        return;
```